# OSX Lion: problems with installation of XCode 4.3

Tags: osx-lion, xcode

I've downloaded Xcode 4.3 and been trying to install it on OSX lion but I've the following error in the logfile

```
SoftwareUpdate Scan: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 
"The Internet connection appears to be offline." UserInfo=0x7fcc71e646b0 
{NSUnderlyingError=0x7fcc71e653c0 "The Internet connection appears to be offline.", 
NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://swscan.apple.com/content/catalogs/others/index-lion-
snowleopard-leopard.merged-1.sucatalog, 
NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://swscan.apple.com/content/catalogs/others/index-lion-snowleopard-
leopard.merged-1.sucatalog, NSLocalizedDescription=The Internet connection appears to be 
offline.}
```

I tried manually browse urls showed above to check if they're live, and with my internet connection everything is fine. 
Also removed old XCode from the system

```
sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```

but it didn't help I've the same error.

What is the right way to install XCode, what causes this problem?

Thanks,

Sultan

Comment: Do you have any entries in your `hosts` file pointing to `apple.com`?

Comment: Any chance your site requires a web proxy, which you configured in your browser (Firefox?), but not system-wide in "System Preferences > Network > [Interface] > Advanced > Proxies"?

Comment: There is no anything pointing to apple sites

Comment: By the way I just installed XCode from app store and it worked

Comment: Then please answer your own question using the button below. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your attention,

The problem is solved

- sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
- Installed XCode from app store and it worked

Thanks,
Sultan